# display subtitles programmatically in video

Tags: android

i want to display the subtitles in video from URL reference in android. I search on Internet to resolve my query but unfortunately nothing positive had been happened. Is there any example which demonstrates this  http://www.ittiam.com/IttiamAdmin/Downloads/RenderingSubtitlesinAndroid201192914525892.pdf Kindly help.

Comment: try [vitamio livrary](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/)

Comment: Good work @ChiragShah. Use Vitamio SDK or ask Ittiam team for help.

In case you want to develop your own logic to show the Subtitle on top of running video than [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714121/android-native-video-player-with-subtitles) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you...i have used vitamio livrary. Now can you please guide me what is the correct way to give subtitle_path in VideoViewSubtitle.java file. I can manage to play video but have not cleared with subtitle display.

Comment: Thank you for the library and suggestion. However can you save the video with these subtitles so if you play it on a player it will show the subtitles?

Comment: You can play video on Surface view and use TextView to display title.